# Access the interior color of a cell style from VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

My workbook has a cell style that is called "Normal Formula". Is it possible to access the interior color of this cell style from VBA?

I've tried:

```
rCell.Interior.Color = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal Formula").Interior.Color
```

but VBE gives me an object required error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I found was from msdn for word. When I replaced activedocument with thisworkbook, the code worked.

```
rCell.Interior.Color = ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal Formula").Interior.Color
```